# how to Group array key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am getting API response as below

```
[{id: 1, fileName:"abc.png",docid:"123",controlNumb:"11"},
{id:2,fileName:"mno.png",docid:"121",controlNumb:"12"},
{id:1,fileName:"def.png",docid:"120",controlNumb:"11"},
{id:3,fileName:"xyz.png",docid:"125",controlNumb:"13"},
{id:2,fileName:"rst.png", docid:"126",controlNumb:"12"}]
```

what I want to convert in

```
[{id: 1, fileName:["abc.png",def.png],docid:["123","120"],controlNumb:"11"},
{id: 2, fileName:["mno.png",rst.png],docid:["121","126"],controlNumb:"12"}
{id: 3, fileName:["xyz.png"],docid:["125"],controlNumb:"11"}
```

I tried the .reduce method and it's giving the same output but fileName and type are showing objects I cant use a map to those keys.

incase if the id is blank I want to group by controlNumb

below code, I tried

```
 let newDirectory = Object.values(
       this.state.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
         if (!acc[item.id])
          acc[item.id] = {
           id: item.id,
           controlNumb: item.controlNumb,
            docid: [],
            fileName: [],
          };
         acc[item.id].docid.push(item.docid);
         acc[item.id].fileName.push(item.fileName);
         return acc;
       }, {})
     );
     console.log("newDirectory", newDirectory);
```

above code returns array but its type of object so i can't use map inside filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can loop over the data, and group the values based on the same `id`, then expand the properties of `fileName` and `docid` to `arrays`, for example:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, fileName: "abc.png", docid: "123", controlNumb: "11" },
{ id: 2, fileName: "mno.png", docid: "121", controlNumb: "12" },
{ id: 1, fileName: "def.png", docid: "120", controlNumb: "11" },
{ id: 3, fileName: "xyz.png", docid: "125", controlNumb: "13" },
{ id: 2, fileName: "rst.png", docid: "126", controlNumb: "12" }];

const parsedData = [];

for (const item of data) {
  const index = parsedData.findIndex(storedItem => storedItem.id === item.id);
  if (index === -1) {
    const newItem = { ...item, fileName: [item.fileName], docid: [item.docid] }
    parsedData.push(newItem);
    }
  else {
    parsedData[index].fileName.push(item.fileName);
    parsedData[index].docid.push(item.docid);
  }
}

console.log(parsedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of operation I suggest using Lodash. It's a very cool library with tons of useful methods to help you on your project.

https://lodash.com/docs/

Lodash has a `groupBy` method, easy to use, and I believe it does what you are looking for. So in your case, you would have something like this:

```
const newDirectory = _.groupBy(this.state.data, "id");
```

You basically pass the array you want to group, along with the key name you want to group by.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: thanks for the response but I wanted to do it without a library. and @Marcos code worked for me.