# how to show json array by hierarchical sub cats in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I receive through api one json  with this structure.
And I want to display the objects as follows.
But I do not know in map array by react js how to get in objects and sub-objects.

json code:

```
 [
  {
    "term_id": 15,
    "name": "Uncategorized",
    "children": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "term_id": 21,
    "name": "Clothing",
    "children": [
      {
        "term_id": 24,
        "name": "Accessories",
        "children": [
       {
        "term_id": 24,
        "name": "Accessories",
        "children": [
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "term_id": 23,
        "name": "Hoodies",
        "children": [
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "term_id": 22,
        "name": "Tshirts",
        "children": [
          
        ]
      }         
        ]
      },
      {
        "term_id": 23,
        "name": "Hoodies",
        "children": [
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "term_id": 22,
        "name": "Tshirts",
        "children": [
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "term_id": 26,
    "name": "Decor",
    "children": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "term_id": 25,
    "name": "Music",
    "children": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

**And I want to show it this way:**

Uncategorized

Clothing

-Accessories

--Bike

--Engine

---Bench

--Airplane

Hoodies

Tshirts

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question to this one. So I'll just leave the link and copy paste the answer as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838788/15160090

Just let me know if you have any questions about this and I'll elaborate further on what you'd need to do.

---

For this kind of operation I suggest using Lodash. It's a very cool library with tons of useful methods to help you on your project.

https://lodash.com/docs/

Lodash has a `groupBy` method, easy to use, and I believe it does what you are looking for. So in your case, you would have something like this:

```
const categories = _.groupBy(data, "name");
```

You basically pass the array you want to group, along with the key name you want to group by.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I actually want to have the categories like this in React Native:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IEKt.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function to solve your issue

```
function recursive(arrayJson, level=0)
{
   let childrenComp = null
   If(arrayJson.children)
       childrenComp = recursive(arrayJson.children, level++)

   return <>
       <Text>{level > 0 && “-“.repeat(level)}arrayJson.name</Text>
       {childrenComp}
       </>
}

render(
    const components = arrayJson && this.recursive(arrayJson)
    return <View>{components}</View>
)
```

Comment: Your solution is right
But in React Native, such a function is needed.

    const lapsList = arrayJson.map((item) => {
        
        return (
          <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text>-{item.children.name}</Text>  ==========> This method does not work
            </View>
        )
      })

Comment: I have updated my answer see if this helps